# Riemann Zeta function (functional equation)

Tags: riemann-zeta

Can someone confirm the validity of the following identity:

$\zeta(s)=(\frac{y}{2\pi})^{0.5-x}e^{-i(y\ln(\frac{y}{2\pi})-y-\frac{\pi}{4})}\zeta(1-s)$ where $s=x+iy$ and $y>0$.

Comment: No. The [correct formula is there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation)

Comment: That is correct, is an approximation and not an equality.

Comment: If you want an approximation, substitute the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) for $\Gamma(1-s)$ in the functional equation

Comment: Let us suppose that is an equality, is this enough for the validity of Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: @ int.math what do you mean ? The functional equation has been proven by Riemann in 1859. It is necessary for the RH, but of course not sufficient.